# Disable indentation in enumerate temporarily

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, enumerate

I would like to place an unindented `\fbox` inside an `enumerate` environment.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Some text.
    \par\fbox{a}
    \item Some more text.
\end{enumerate}
```

The above code produces:

```
1. Some text.
   a
2. Some more text.
```

Is there a way to get the following?

```
1. Some text.
a
2. Some more text.
```

Of course I could fiddle around with `\hspace{somenegativelength}`. However, is there nothing like `\reallynoindent`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could interrupt and resume your `enumerate` with the `enumitem` package, so that the `\fbox{a}` becomes part of the main body again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\noindent{}Text before.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text.
\end{enumerate}
\fbox{a}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Some more text
\end{enumerate}
Text after.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Making it an item on its own is a way to go:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Some text.
    \item[\fbox{a}]
    \item Some more text.
\end{enumerate}
```

To answer your question about `\reallynoindent`: Process of making a list "indented" is not the same as making a paragraph indented. If you put `\the\parindent` inside default `enumerate`, you'll get `0pt`. The point here is that the whole left margin is increased by the amount of "indent". You can check that this is true by putting `\the\leftmargin` in the list, which in my case output soomething like `27.3747pt`. If you want to "reallynoindent", you can do the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some text.

{\setlength{\parindent}{-\leftmargin}\fbox{a}} Foo bar

\item Some more text.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of how margins work inside `enumerate`. A limitation of your solution is that it only works if `\box{a}` is quite short. The custom label expands to the left.