# No indentation for non-item within itemize

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

When using itemize list, I would like to include text which is not part of the bullet points. Is it possible not to indent it the way items are indented?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item One
Subsequently, we only want to count the cases...
\item Two
The subsequent order of the other neighbors...
\item Three
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Using  `enumitem.sty` you can easily stop and resume itemizations and enumerations.

Comment: The following is probably a source duplicate: [Disable indentation in enumerate temporarily](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98060/5764)

Comment: Did you try using more paragraphs in an item?  E.g. `\item One \par One continues \par And again \item Two`.  This produces indentation, but no bullet. See the link in the comment above for more info.

Comment: Is this the extent of your usage? Will `One`, `Two`, and `Three` be what is contained as an `\item` in your `itemize`, followed by a "lengthy" discussion afterwards (which you don't want indented)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the help of a `\vbox` you can "escape" from the indentation in a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\NoIndent[1]{%
  \par\vbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\NoIndent{\lipsum[4]}
\item Two
\NoIndent{\lipsum[2]}
\item Three
\NoIndent{\lipsum[1]}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **barbara beeton** has noticed in her comment, the above solution doesn't admit page breaks inside `\NoIndent`; here's a solution admitting page breaks, using `\vsplit` to break the `\vbox` (this technique was explained by **egreg** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20903) to [Breakable vboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20901)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newbox\totalbox
\newbox\partialbox
\newdimen\partialboxdim

\newenvironment{nibox}
  {\par\vskip-6pt\setbox\totalbox=\vbox\bgroup}
  {\egroup\splitnibox}

\def\splitnibox{%
  \ifvoid\totalbox\par
  \else\continuesplitting\fi}

\def\continuesplitting{\null% In case this starts a new page
  \dimen255=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\pageshrink-6pt\relax
  \ifdim\ht\totalbox<\dimen255
    \setbox\partialbox=\box\totalbox
    \unvbox\partialbox
  \else
    \setbox\partialbox=\vsplit\totalbox to\dimen255
    \unvbox\partialbox\eject
  \fi
  \splitnibox}

\newcommand\NoIndent[1]{\begin{nibox}#1\end{nibox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\NoIndent{\lipsum[4]}
\item Two
\NoIndent{\lipsum[2-3]}
\item Three
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but what if one of these non-indented blocks needs to be broken at the end of a page?  i think this would be effective only for very short insertions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes; the original solution didn't admit page breaks. I've updated my answer with a new solution amending this.

Comment: A trifle too complicated. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Perhaps, but in the process I learnt how to split boxes, so it was worth doing it.

Answer (score 11):

You can revert to `\parshape0` inside a group, so the previous setting will be resumed after the group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\NoIndent[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \par
  \parshape0
  #1\par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\NoIndent{\lipsum[4]}
\item Two
\NoIndent{\lipsum[2]}
\item Three
\NoIndent{\lipsum[1]}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This has no problems with page breaks.

[image]