# Non-indent lstlisting code block in enumerate?

Tags: listings, indentation, enumerate

I'd like to insert a block of code in an enumerate list, but I don't want the natural indent from enumerate with the block. For example,

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Primitive Version
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Implementation
        \paragraph{} The key segment of code is:
\begin{lstlisting}[style=ccode]
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I've checked several solutions such as [No indentation for non-item within itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131637/no-indentation-for-non-item-within-itemize) but all of them resulted in errors as I cannot use `lstlisting` as a parameter.

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \lst@insertargs.
```

How should I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can adjust the left margin of the `lstlisting` using the `xleftmargin` key-value. Setting it to a combination of the list depths from each respective level (`-\leftmargini` for the first, an additional `-\leftmarginii` for the second, `-\leftmarginiii` for the third, etc.), you can push the listing back to the original left margin of the text as if it were set *without* the list indentations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\noindent
X \dotfill X

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Y \dotfill Y
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Z \dotfill Z

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,xleftmargin=\dimexpr-\leftmarginii-\leftmargini]
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

    \item Z\dotfill Z
  \end{enumerate}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,xleftmargin=-\leftmargini]
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
  \item Y \dotfill Y
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

The total left margin at any depth is given by `\@totalleftmargin`. We can utilise this by adjusting `xleftmargin` in the following way:

```
<list above>

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,xleftmargin=\dimexpr-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname]
  <code>
\end{lstlisting}

<list below>
```

Comment: You could use `xleftmargin=\dimexpr-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname`  to avoid to have two different versions depending on the level.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach which needs no manual adjustments depending on current list depth.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
% command \NOINDENT to be used in a group   
\newcommand*\NOINDENT{\@@par   % clear parshape parameters
% fool list-awareness code (as supposedly in lstlisting, not checked)
      \@totalleftmargin\z@ \@listdepth\z@ \rightmargin\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
X \dotfill X

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Y \dotfill Y
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Z \dotfill Z

{\NOINDENT\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}}
% the whole \NOINDENT\begin...\end must be enclosed in braces!
    \item Z\dotfill Z
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item W\dotfill W

{\NOINDENT\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}}

      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

  \item Y \dotfill Y

{\NOINDENT\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```